# How to include *.so library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I read many threads how to add a *.so library to Android Studio, but none of them works, especially when it comes to the point of text: This does not work with the newer xxx (Android Studio, gradle, ...)

Can we make a fresh start please. I got:

Android Studio 0.6.0

From Project Structure I see:

SDK Location:

```
/usr/share/android-studio/data/sdk
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

Project:

```
Gradle version 1.10
Android Plugin Version 0.11.+
```

Modules/app:
Properties:

Compile Sdk Version 19
Build Tools Version 19.1.0

Dependencies:

```
{dir=libs, include=[*.jar]} Compile

{dir=libs, include=[*.so]}  Provided

m com.android.support: appcompat -v7:19.+   Compile
```

I got the *.so files pre-compiled and at the demo app they are working. I have to change the source code of the app, so I need to rebuild with the same *.so files.

Comment: add a .so file from directory outside android project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713933/add-so-prebuilt-library-from-another-directory-to-apk

Comment: Check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977264/8034839

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**Current Solution**

Create the folder `project/app/src/main/jniLibs`, and then put your `*.so` files within their abi folders in that location. E.g.,

```
project/
├──libs/
|  └── *.jar       <-- if your library has jar files, they go here
├──src/
   └── main/
       ├── AndroidManifest.xml
       ├── java/
       └── jniLibs/ 
           ├── arm64-v8a/                       <-- ARM 64bit
           │   └── yourlib.so
           ├── armeabi-v7a/                     <-- ARM 32bit
           │   └── yourlib.so
           └── x86/                             <-- Intel 32bit
               └── yourlib.so
```

**Deprecated solution**

Add both code snippets in your module gradle.build file as a dependency:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
```

How to create this custom jar:

```
task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

Same answer can also be found in related question: [Include .so library in apk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio?rq=1)

Comment: `Compile` task has been deprecated. Use `JavaCompile` instead (from related answers)

Comment: where should i put the tasks?

Comment: Please try first the jniLibs folder solution. This tasks should be put into your app/library gradle.build file.

Comment: Reference for the `jniLibs` directory path at [Gradle Plugin User Guide - Project Structure](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure)

Comment: see also here (lists the different architecture sub-folders): https://www.cumulations.com/blogs/9/ImportinglibraryhavingnativecodeinAndroidstudio

Comment: My output is a static file, i have tried but its not package into the apk

Comment: How to call Native library method in Activity

Comment: Hi I want to also know where can I add my includes folder for my header files as I'm writing a C++ native code

Comment: It's very strange that If my app named libxxx.so, it can copy, but xxx.so, not copied.

Comment: Outdated now. Please use the answer by @Vasanth instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28430334/3397618

Answer (score 262):

**Adding .so Library in Android Studio 1.0.2**

1. Create Folder "jniLibs" inside "src/main/"
2. Put all your .so libraries inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder
3. Folder structure looks like,

   |--app:

   |--|--src:

   |--|--|--main

   |--|--|--|--jniLibs

   |--|--|--|--|--armeabi

   |--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files

   |--|--|--|--|--x86

   |--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
4. No extra code requires just sync your project and run your application.

   **Reference**

   https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle/tree/master/src/main

Comment: Thank you. I found this answer to be the, by far, easiest way of solving the issue while still keeping the gradle config white-noise to a minimum.

Comment: Using this method but I have a xxx.so.9 file and it is not copied. Getting error about that file is not found. How to make it copied?

Comment: This isn't working with the June 16, 2015 beta version of Studio

Comment: this is correct answer, working in Android Studio 1.2.2. checked and verified.

Comment: Working with Android Studio 1.3.1.

Comment: Worked for me, thanx! with gradle-experimental

Comment: Worked for me thnx . on android studio 2.1.2 :)

Comment: What about Android Studio 2.2? I have 7 .so files for 7 archs. However how can I include them in my project.

Comment: Worked for me on Android Studio 2.2 October 2016. Thanks ☺

Comment: Worked on Android Studio 2.2.3. Thanks !

Comment: isn't working for me, getting  
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError "couldn't find "libFPEComponent.so"

Comment: What about x86_64. jniLibs/x86_64 isn't working for me :(

Comment: Still correct answer. 

@VikasPandey you load up FPECComponent, not lib  + .so name

Comment: works with Android Studio 3.2.1, great! Still not documented anywhere !???

Comment: @Vasantha LInk not valid

Comment: Worked on Android Studio 4.1.1

Comment: Worked on Android Studio 4.1.3

Comment: @NorbertM documented here https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs SEVEN YEARS LATER. ;-O

Comment: also you should add    ndk { abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' }

Comment: Its working well in Debug mode but never works in release mode

Answer (score 38):

**Solution 1 : Creation of a JniLibs folder**

Create a folder called “jniLibs” into your app and the folders containing your *.so inside.
The "jniLibs" folder needs to be created in the same folder as your "Java" or "Assets" folders.

**Solution 2 : Modification of  the build.gradle file**

If you don’t want to create a new folder and keep your *.so files into the libs folder, it is possible !

In that case, just add your *.so files into the libs folder (please respect the same architecture as the solution 1 : libs/armeabi/.so for instance) and modify the build.gradle file of your app to add the source directory of the jniLibs.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ["libs"]
    }
}
```

You will have more explanations, with screenshots to help you  here ( Step 6 ):

http://blog.guillaumeagis.eu/setup-andengine-with-android-studio/

**EDIT** It had to be jniLibs.srcDirs, not jni.srcDirs - edited the code. The directory can be a [relative] path that points outside of the project directory.

Comment: Solution 2 doesn't work for me. I get a build error: "Could not find property 'jni' on source set 'main'."

Comment: The secret was 'The "jniLibs" folder needs to be created in the same folder as your "Java" or "Assets" folders.'. Thanks!

Comment: Method 1 allowed me to compile correctly, second one created a "cpp" folder in AS and gave me error about missing C++ compiler

Comment: Solution 2 had to use jniLibs.srcDirs, not jni.srcDirs to allow specifying the location of native libraries (the path can be relative or absolute and can point even outside the project directory).

Comment: For Solution 2 you need to place the `source Sets {` code under the `android {` section

Comment: for me adding `'src/main/jniLibs'` to `jniLibs.srcDirs` is needed, thx!

Answer (score 27):

***.so library in Android Studio**

You have to generate jniLibs folder inside main in android Studio projects and put your all .so files inside. You can also integrate this line in build.gradle

**compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.so'])**

It's work perfectly

|--app:

|--|--src:

|--|--|--main

|--|--|--|--jniLibs

|--|--|--|--|--armeabi

|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files

This is the project structure.

Comment: Adding **.so** in **compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['.jar','.so'])** solved my prb. thnx

Comment: If it is still after below solution, try android ndk r10e

Answer (score 11):

This is my build.gradle file, Please note the line

```
jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
```

This will include libs's *.so file to apk.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Android NDK official `hello-libs` CMake example**

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs

Just worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10 host, Android Studio 3, Android SDK 26, so I strongly recommend that you base your project on it.

The shared library is called `libgperf`, the key code parts are:

- [hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt):

  ```
  // -L
  add_library(lib_gperf SHARED IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(lib_gperf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
            ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgperf.so)

  // -I
  target_include_directories(hello-libs PRIVATE
                             ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/include)
  // -lgperf
  target_link_libraries(hello-libs
                        lib_gperf)
  ```
- [app/build.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs/app/build.gradle):

  ```
  android {
      sourceSets {
          main {
              // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
              jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../distribution/gperf/lib']
  ```

  Then, if you look under `/data/app` on the device, `libgperf.so` will be there as well.
- on C++ code, use: `#include <gperf.h>`
- header location: `hello-libs/distribution/gperf/include/gperf.h`
- lib location: `distribution/gperf/lib/arm64-v8a/libgperf.so`
- If you only support some architectures, see: [Gradle Build NDK target only ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278152/gradle-build-ndk-target-only-arm/47558314#47558314)

The example git tracks the prebuilt shared libraries, but it also contains the build system to actually build them as well: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs/gen-libs

Answer (score 4):

I have solved a similar problem using external native lib dependencies that are packaged inside of jar files. Sometimes these architecture dependend libraries are packaged alltogether inside one jar, sometimes they are split up into several jar files. so i wrote some buildscript to scan the jar dependencies for native libs and sort them into the correct android lib folders. Additionally this also provides a way to download dependencies that not found in maven repos which is currently usefull to get JNA working on android because not all native jars are published in public maven repos.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myappid"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/jniLibs", "$buildDir/native-libs"]
        }
    }
}

def urlFile = { url, name ->
    File file = new File("$buildDir/download/${name}.jar")
    file.parentFile.mkdirs()
    if (!file.exists()) {
        new URL(url).withInputStream { downloadStream ->
            file.withOutputStream { fileOut ->
                fileOut << downloadStream
            }
        }
    }
    files(file.absolutePath)
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.2.0'
    compile urlFile('https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4.2.2/lib/native/android-arm.jar?raw=true', 'jna-android-arm')
    compile urlFile('https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4.2.2/lib/native/android-armv7.jar?raw=true', 'jna-android-armv7')
    compile urlFile('https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4.2.2/lib/native/android-aarch64.jar?raw=true', 'jna-android-aarch64')
    compile urlFile('https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4.2.2/lib/native/android-x86.jar?raw=true', 'jna-android-x86')
    compile urlFile('https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4.2.2/lib/native/android-x86-64.jar?raw=true', 'jna-android-x86_64')
    compile urlFile('https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4.2.2/lib/native/android-mips.jar?raw=true', 'jna-android-mips')
    compile urlFile('https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4.2.2/lib/native/android-mips64.jar?raw=true', 'jna-android-mips64')
}
def safeCopy = { src, dst ->
    File fdst = new File(dst)
    fdst.parentFile.mkdirs()
    fdst.bytes = new File(src).bytes

}

def archFromName = { name ->
    switch (name) {
        case ~/.*android-(x86-64|x86_64|amd64).*/:
            return "x86_64"
        case ~/.*android-(i386|i686|x86).*/:
            return "x86"
        case ~/.*android-(arm64|aarch64).*/:
            return "arm64-v8a"
        case ~/.*android-(armhf|armv7|arm-v7|armeabi-v7).*/:
            return "armeabi-v7a"
        case ~/.*android-(arm).*/:
            return "armeabi"
        case ~/.*android-(mips).*/:
            return "mips"
        case ~/.*android-(mips64).*/:
            return "mips64"
        default:
            return null
    }
}

task extractNatives << {
    project.configurations.compile.each { dep ->
        println "Scanning ${dep.name} for native libs"
        if (!dep.name.endsWith(".jar"))
            return
        zipTree(dep).visit { zDetail ->
            if (!zDetail.name.endsWith(".so"))
                return
            print "\tFound ${zDetail.name}"
            String arch = archFromName(zDetail.toString())
            if(arch != null){
                println " -> $arch"
                safeCopy(zDetail.file.absolutePath,
                        "$buildDir/native-libs/$arch/${zDetail.file.name}")
            } else {
                println " -> No valid arch"
            }
        }
    }
}

preBuild.dependsOn(['extractNatives'])
```

Answer (score 3):

I have android studio 4.1.2 and when I tried to set the ndk path in File -> Project Structure -> Sdk Location it would ask me to download the ndk even though it was already installed, I set the NDK_HOME, ANDROID_NDK_HOME and PATH environmental variables and nothing. The only thing that worked for me was manually setting the ndk version in the local.properties, creating a jniLibs (yes with this exact name) folder with the ABIs and their respective .so files and specifying the abi filters and ndk version in the build.gradle. Hope this saves someone else from a headache.

local.properties

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\22.0.7026061
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    ndkVersion '22.0.7026061'
}
```

...\app\src\main\

[image]

Inside the jniLibs folder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use native-library (so files)
You need to add some codes in the "build.gradle" file.

This code is for cleaing "armeabi" directory and copying 'so' files into "armeabi" while 'clean project'.

```
task copyJniLibs(type: Copy) {
    from 'libs/armeabi'
    into 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(copyJniLibs)
}
clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyJniLibs'
```

I've been referred from the below.
https://gist.github.com/pocmo/6461138