# How to import the Chilkat Android libs to Android Studio?

Tags: android, import, android-studio, chilkat

I am using using `Android Studio 0.8.9` and I am trying to import `Chilkat Android libs` to my project by following the instructions given [**here**](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatAndroid.asp). I have done all the imports and my project structure looks something like this.

but the statement

```
import com.chilkatsoft.*;
```

gives the error

`Error:(8, 1) error: package com.chilkatsoft does not exist`

Can anyone help me to integrate the `Chilkat Android libs` and help me to create the first instance of CkXml class?

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am stuck on the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a subModule why dont you add its as a Module, you can add it in `File->Import Module` and select the folder under src.  It will be added as a module, then go to `project settings` or `project structure` and in your main module click on the `Dependencies` tab and in the green Plus Icon you can add a submodule as Dependency, select that module and Rebuild if necesary this has to be enough.

Otherwise if this dont work add the folder and be sure to hit `Build->Rebuild Project` so android studio recognize the new classes.

Good Luck

Comment: While importing it says that I have to Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse project.

Comment: I downloaded the chilkat library and in the Instructions says to copy the source directory and rebuild the project, did you Pressed `Build->Rebuild Project` ? That worked for me

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. Will you please check my import from the above screenshot.

Comment: ok Below `src` Create another folder called `main` then inside it another called `java` and then add the com folder below it, confirm that the folder turns out blue

Comment: hmm it has helped :) but now I am getting some other error. `Couldn't load chilkat from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.goppinath.chilkattest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.goppinath.chilkattest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null`

Comment: You have reached the answer... please consider lib and libs from the Chilkat documentation: libs/armeabi, libs/armeabi-v7a, lib/mips, lib/x86

Comment: Look in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio-really) how to add a native-library in Android Studio, its just add it into the lib folder and add some clauses to your build.gradle

Comment: Thanks, but I could not over come the last problem.