# Android. Couldn't load gpuimage-library

Tags: android, android-camera, opengl-es-2.0, android-gpuimageview

I just downloaded GPUImageLibrary 1.2.3 snapshot and import the library and the sample project. 
In the sample app, when i pick image from gallery, everything works fine. But everytime i try to pick image from camera, the app crashes.

```
package jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage;

public class GPUImageNativeLibrary {
    static {
         //there is the crash happened
        System.loadLibrary("gpuimage-library");
    }

    public static native void YUVtoRBGA(byte[] yuv, int width, int height, int[] out);

    public static native void YUVtoARBG(byte[] yuv, int width, int height, int[] out);
}
```

Here is the stacktrace

`01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 3277
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839): Process: jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.sample, PID: 15839
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gpuimage-library from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.sample-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.sample-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839):    at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageNativeLibrary.(GPUImageNativeLibrary.java:21)
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839):    at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer$1.run(GPUImageRenderer.java:141)
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839):    at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer.runAll(GPUImageRenderer.java:126)
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839):    at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer.onDrawFrame(GPUImageRenderer.java:115)
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1533)
01-20 17:11:25.226: E/AndroidRuntime(15839):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1247)`

I don't know what to do about this error. I think that this error is not code-related. Please give me some direction.

Sorry for my terrible english.

Comment: Hey @Denny Wahyu Pratono You solved this..???

If Yes, Then Please tell me how to solved this you.

I am also Use this gpuimage-library in my App...

But it gives me an error same as your error.

Please Help me...):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile native C file located in jni folder, with ndk-build to create libary in libs folder, with extension .so.

Comment: File should be auto generated when you compile your app, so you can copy it and put in the right folders: src/main/jniLibs/armeabi and src/main/jniLibs/x86. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio