# Couldn't find "libgpuimage-library.so" android studio with GPUImage 1.3.0

Tags: android, java-native-interface, gpuimage

Gettings this exception while starting project with GPUIMage library. Looks Like the problem is the same as [Android. Couldn't load gpuimage-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043236/android-couldnt-load-gpuimage-library). But information from the answer is not enough.

Can someone help me with it? Thanks anyway.

Exception refers to this class:

```
package jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage;

public class GPUImageNativeLibrary {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("gpuimage-library");
    }

    public static native void YUVtoRBGA(byte[] yuv, int width, int height, int[] out);

    public static native void YUVtoARBG(byte[] yuv, int width, int height, int[] out);
}
```

exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2588
Process: com.blah, PID: 490                                                   
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.blah-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.blah-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgpuimage-library.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageNativeLibrary.<clinit>(GPUImageNativeLibrary.java:21)
at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer$1.run(GPUImageRenderer.java:141)
at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer.runAll(GPUImageRenderer.java:126)
at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer.onDrawFrame(GPUImageRenderer.java:115)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1535)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. To solve it I to copied the libgpuimage-library.so to the right folders:

1. Compile and launch your app, a **libgpuimage-library.so** file will be generated. Search in your project folder
2. Copy this file to your app folders: **src/main/jniLibs/armeabi** and **src/main/jniLibs/x86**, create folders if doesn't exist
3. Run the app, now it should work the camera loading the GPUImage library.

Answer (score 0):

Just change GPUImage 1.3.0 to 1.2.3:

```
compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.2.3'
```

Then, it will work.