# Place file during apk installation

Tags: android, qt

There is a qt android program. It has config file. It is needed that user can edit config file. So config file should be placed somewhere (sd card maybe). Now config file is in resources and program places it during the first run. Config file is not available to the user before the first run. And the question is how to make program putting config file on sd(or somewhere else) while installing apk. 
I found similar question [How to copy numbered/versioned .so file during apk install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030863/how-to-copy-numbered-versioned-so-file-during-apk-install) but unfortunately there are no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything during installation.  There's no hook there.  You have to do it the first time you're run after instal.