# Multiple folders under a single module in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-experimental

[image]

I am trying to structure my project as shown in the image:

```
/src/main/folder_1/file_1.cpp
/src/main/folder_2/file_2.cpp
```

But android studio complaints for both `file_1.cpp` and `file2.cpp` as

> "Gradle files have changed since last project sync. A project sync may be necessary for the IDE work properly."

And sync doesn't help.

Please note that I am using Experimental-Gradle:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0
```

Comment: Your image shows `src/main/common_folderfolder_1/`, and not `src/main/folder_1/`... Please clarify which you want. Regardless, moving those files around does not affect Gradle.

Comment: And C++ files? Why are you trying to place them in `src/main` at all? They should be in `jniLibs` or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include \*.so library in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have problem related to the SDK.
**Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (android studio)**

1. Let Gradle rebuild your auto-genrated files by click **Build | Rebuild** 
 
2. Also try [Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)