# Add .so (prebuilt) library from another directory to APK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to include my .so library from another directory. Compiling my project works fine. But when I run it, it gives me

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.gimikapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.gimikapp-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libtheprebuiltlib.so"

Common solutions I see in SO is this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

Tried both

```
jniLibs.srcDirs = ['C:\\svn\\sys_libs']
```

and

```
jniLibs.srcDirs = ['C:/svn/sys_libs']
```

How do you actually point it to another directory outside your Android project?

This is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library( native-lib
            SHARED
            src/main/cpp/source/native-lib.cpp )
add_library(theprebuiltlib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(theprebuiltlib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
            C:/svn/sys_libs/libtheprebuiltlib.so)
target_include_directories(
            native-lib PRIVATE
            src/main/cpp/source/
            C:/svn/sys_includes/)
find_library( log-lib
            log)
target_link_libraries( native-lib
            theprebuiltlib
            ${log-lib})
```

And here is my gradle setup for my JNI:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi'
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['C:/svn/sys_libs']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds

Comment: check this solution https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d

Comment: the medium.com link discusses a solution when .so is inside the android project. mine is outside the project, specifically in C:/svn/sys_libs/

Comment: I think you have to copy the .so file in the jniLibs folder manually or just link statically if you have a static version.

Comment: First, to eliminate some situations that might cause the problem, check your APK file. If it has `lib` folder, what files do you find there? Android Studio has *Analyze APK* in the top menu.

Comment: I used Analyze APK, ```lib``` folder is empty

Comment: Let's try to remove the `jniLibs` setting from build.gradle, and check how the APK changes. BTW, maybe the part where you launch **cmake** is incorrect, please post it here, too.

Comment: with or without ```jniLibs.srcDirs```, it's the same. "launch cmake" - what do you mean? the cmake declaration in gradle?

Comment: There are usually two externalNativeBuild blocks in build.gradle. But just in case, show this file as it is, there are too many ways to get it wrong.

Comment: added. hopefully it helps you help me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you have NDK r17 installed and Android plugin v.3.1.0 or higher (we don't see this in the published fragment of build.gradle).

But you set **abiFilters** to `armeabi`, which has been dropped. You should set it to `armeabi-v7a`, and make sure that `libtheprebuiltlib.so` is also built for this ABI, or you can [download an older version of NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases) and in build.gradle dependencies set

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

You can force the latest plugin handle `armeabi` if you set it explicitly:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi'
        }
    }
}
```

(in your script, it is under **android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.ndk**, so has no effect).

One mistake in your **build.gradle**, it should read

```
android {
  sourceSets {
     main { 
       jniLibs.srcDir 'C:/svn/sys_libs' 
     }
   }
}
```

when you have the file `C:\svn\sys_libs\armeabi\libtheprebuiltlib.so`. But this does not explain why **cmake** does not work as expected.

Comment: thanks for continued support. I am using NDK r16 but using the latest gradle. (giving you +1 though as this answer might be helpful to others.)

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. i tried gradle 3.0.1, ndk r16, and moved abiFilters to android.defaultConfig.ndk. i am sure my .so file is for armeabi

Comment: OK, let's step back then. Comment out the `externalNativeBuild` block(s), and see if the prebuilt lib gets packed (as pointed by **jniLibs**).

Comment: removed all externalNativeBuild blocks. set android.sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['C:/svn/sys_libs'], .so is still missing.

Comment: what about a relative path instead ?

Comment: @OlivierMATROT sure, you can use relative paths anywhere. In gradle, all paths should be relative to the gradle project directory, which is where build.gradle file resides.

Answer (score 2):

For NDK r16 and Gradle plugin v3.1.2, here is the step by step solution (thanks to @Alex Cohn).

1. Set `android.sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDir` to point to the location of external .so

   ```
   android {
       sourceSets {
           main { 
               jniLibs.srcDir 'C:/svn/sys_libs' 
           }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure that your external .so is located in the above path (step1), appended by correct architecture. In my case, it is `armeabi`, thus my .so is in

   ```
   C:/svn/sys_libs/armeabi/libtheprebuiltlib.so
   ```
3. Move `ndk` from `android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.ndk` to `android.defaultConfig.ndk` like so

   ```
   android {
       defaultConfig {
           ndk {
               abiFilters 'armeabi'
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Make sure that CMakeLists.txt points to the complete path with proper architecture.

   ```
   set_target_properties(theprebuiltlib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
           C:/svn/sys_libs/armeabi/libtheprebuiltlib.so)
   ```