# Implementing Lib .so Files in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, .so

My research team at school is trying to implement the futronics' fingerprint scanner into our app. Im new to android and java in general and I do not understand how to add these libraries to my project. The files given were .so files in armeabi folders.

Comment: did you search online for a solution??

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio