# how to ndk setting finished with non-zero exit value 2 on android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to build `Gstreamer` source and it needs `NDK`.

I am setting `SDK Manager` -> `Android SDK` -> `SDK Tools` -> `NDK` install

and I set `local.properties` `dk:dir="C\:\\Users\\ddd\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle`.

After setting ndk, I try to build it, but execution failed.

`Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'. > Process 'command 'C:\Users\ddd\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd" finished with non-zero exit value 2`  message.

How to set ndk on android?

Answer (score 11):

To find the specific issue, check the **Build** tab in Android Studio to see which task is failing. For me it was task "cleanNative".

Then run this task manually from **Terminal** with **--debug** option.

On Mac or Linux:

```
./gradlew cleanNative --debug
```

On Windows:

```
gradlew cleanNative --debug
```

From logs, you can then see why it is failing. In my case it was the wrong ABI settings:

```
10:24:27.140 [QUIET] [system.out] Android NDK: The armeabi ABI is no longer supported. Use armeabi-v7a.    
10:24:27.140 [QUIET] [system.out] Android NDK: NDK Application 'local' targets unknown ABI(s): armeabi    
10:24:27.140 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/michal-home/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/setup-app.mk:79: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
10:24:27.140 [QUIET] [system.out] Android NDK: Please fix the APP_ABI definition in /path-to-app/app/src/main/jni/Application.mk
```

Answer (score 9):

1. What I infer from above is that you have already installed NDK, make sure you also install **CMake and LLDB**. (Restart Android Studio after install)
2. If the problem persists even after that, try deleting the **"obj"** folder within your ndk library (located at "yourLibary/main/src/obj") and rebuild.

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the NDK is set properly - go to File->Project Structure->SDK Location and make sure the NDK location is properly set. If it is, perhaps the compilation fails due to some problem with the code, and we will need some more info in order to help you.

Comment: The path of your NDK directory should be set via File->Project Structure->SDK Location->Android NDK Location (the last field). If this is not what you are asking, please clarify exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

In my case and project, it was helpful to use privious ndk version([Revision 17c](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases)). So I just have put it in 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle'

Another helpful issue is to put your *.so files within jniLibs folder:

[How to include *.so library in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio/24360361#24360361)

Answer (score 2):

Check your android project path.

I had a similar problem with empty spaces at my folder name. Avoid things like that or ndk can't do the job

> .\Users\User1\Desktop\androidprojects\my project\androidproject1

Instead that use

> .\Users\User1\Desktop\androidprojects\myproject\androidproject1

Comment: This fixed the following error for me: Process 'command 'D:\Android\SDK\ndk\21.1.6352462/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2