# Java android java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad

Tags: java, android

When I start my application , my app is stopped and in logs I see :

```
Process: rest.hello.org.rfidtest, PID: 8581
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/rest.hello.org.rfidtest-2/lib/arm/liblfrfid.so"
```

This couse by line :

```
System.loadLibrary("lfrfid");
```

Comment: I think your .so is not loaded properly.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal  So how I can check this ?or what maybe I can put this ?

Comment: have you created it or you are using from others.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal I get this projecets but it doesn't works

Comment: Check if the so file is where it is expected to be - in "/data/app/rest.hello.org.rfidtest-2/lib/arm/liblfrfid.so" is it there?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki in android studio I don't see this but in folder I see this 
this is a folder : RFIDTest\app\libs\arm

Comment: this file should be copied into your Andorid device on which you run your application, the path is a path realtive to a "data" folder of your app. Check if it is there, if no, check your build script and read about how to make it go there. I'm not a specialist with copying native libraries to a specified app folder in Android, so I can't help you more. Read how to add native library to an Android Studio project, this might be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio

Comment: JNI_OnLoad is the function in the .so that's called when you call loadLibrary.  Its supposed to do any initialization the library needs and possibly load the JNI function table if non-default function mappings are used.  Its returning an error.  You need to debug into the C code of the library and figure out why.

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok , but I have this project in eclipse and it works corretly but when I want to migrate to android studio it doesn't work

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka You found a solution already?