# How do I link against an .so from Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: android, c++, .so

I have an .so as well as header files. I would like to use objects and call functions in this .so file from my Android application, but I do not find a good guide or steps to follow to do this. I use Android Studio 2.3.3. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: check [How to include *.so library in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

this method is very simple. copy your .so file to project into the jniLibs folder
[my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZWFN.png)