# Android ndk_project_path = NULL Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I know this question has been asked before many times but none of the solution is working for me.

Whenever I am trying to run my project I am getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':gpuimage:compileReleaseNdk'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process F:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=F:\Studio_Workspace\klubchat-android\gpuimage\build\intermediates\ndk\release\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-25 NDK_OUT=F:\Studio_Workspace\klubchat-android\gpuimage\build\intermediates\ndk\release\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=F:\Studio_Workspace\klubchat-android\gpuimage\build\intermediates\ndk\release\lib APP_STL=gnustl_shared APP_ABI=all}

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue. I am stuck because of this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You still use the old deprecated NDK approach in Android Studio. I believe it's time to switch to the new version, see https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#ndkCompile

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with the new version but was not able to generate the files that would be required...like CMakeList.txt. Please let me know how to use it.

Comment: The link above shows how you copy the auto-generated **Android.mk** to your project. This may be easier than switching to **cmake**.

Comment: I am not able to find the auto-generated Android.mk file. I have an external library(gpuimage) that i want to use. But not able to use it.

Comment: If you don't have cpp files of your own, you don't need NDK. It's enough to put the prebuilt library in **jniLibs** directory of your project, see instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29234765/192373).

Comment: @AlexCohn : Thanks for the help. Yes I do not have any .cpp file. I have added the "gpuimage" external library as a module. I will check how can I add .so files and will revert you back..

Comment: @Arpit any progress on this?

Comment: @alptugd I have used an older version of NDK and by that my issue is resolved.

Comment: @Arpit can you tell us which version?

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier downgrade from NDK 18 to NDK 17 fixed it for me

Comment: @ thanks I'll look in it