# How to use .so lib in an Android application

Tags: android, android-ndk, libraries, .so

I am working on my master thesis, where I am looking at the security for an IoT device, which is controlled by an android application. At this point, I have reverse engineered the application and looked through the code that came out of it. An interesting discovery is that it is using a .so lib to communicate with the IoT device. So, I would like to build a POC android application where I use this same .so lib.

Now, my question is: how do I do this correctly? 
From what I have understood so far, I need to put the .so lib into the structure: 
`app/jniLib/armeabi-v7a/*.so`

Then I need to load the library in java with:

`static {
    System.loadLibrary("something_lib");
}`

Now if I wish to call a function I should do this by using the "native" keyword: 
[image]

But, as shown in the image above, the function is not being found. So, I properly miss something or am doing something completely wrong.

I've looked at a project on GitHub (https://github.com/SandroMachado/openalpr-android), which is also using .so lib. But I'm having the same experience when I open this project.

I have also had a look at the Android NDK guides (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html), but sadly it did not make me a lot smarter. Here it says something about an Android.mk file, is this still something I need in my situation? If so, I would love if something has a link to a page or can explain to me the missing gaps I have in my knowledge about how to do this.

A simple example/guide for how to use a .so file in a project would be the ultimate solution for me at this point.

Comment: You need to write JNI wrapper around your library

Comment: @Selvin, great! any good references for how to do this correctly? (I'll google to begin with)

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread help you:
[How to include *.so library in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio)

Looks like you should integrate your *.so files into `src/main/jniLib/armeabi-v7a/*.so` rather than `app/jniLib/armeabi-a7/*.so`. Verify that your arm-directory is named `armeabi-v7a` and not `armeabi-a7`.

Comment: I made a typo in my question, thanks for the notification. I have spelled it correctly in my project. I'll have a look at that thread. Thanks!