# Chilkat for Android™ Error: No implementation found chilkatJNI.swig_module_init()

Tags: java, android, scp, chilkat

I wanted to implement Chilkat in my Android app to do scp calls.

I am using Android Studio version 4.2.

So far I have successfully followed the instructions on how to get started.
I followed this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754577/8597586.

And everything went fine.
The new imported libs are found.

It's not the `System.loadLibrary("chilkat")` call that causes the error.

But when I try to create an object, I get the error described in the title.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CkSsh ssh = new CkSsh();
    Log.d(TAG, "Chilkat version: "+ssh.version());

}

static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("chilkat");
    }catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Google has brought me no answers sadly and I can't figure out a way to solve this by myself.

Full Error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.swig_module_init() (tried Java_chilkatsoft_chilkatJNI_swig_1module_1init and Java_chilkatsoft_chilkatJNI_swig_1module_1init__)
    at chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
    at chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.<clinit>(chilkatJNI.java:9720)
    at chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.new_CkSsh(Native Method)
    at chilkatsoft.CkSsh.<init>(CkSsh.java:39)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?