# How do I use .so file functions in my Android app's native code?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I have seen similar questions but I'm not sure if it matches my question.

I have been provided a .so file, whose functions I want to call in my own C++ code. How do I link my C++ file to the .so file. I know how to directly link .so files to Java code via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio).

Is there some way I can do this? I'm thinking something like linking via CMake. Is there some better way?

Please let me know if there's a question like if it's asked before.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How is this question related to Android? On which platform is your C++ code? What is that .so file - what architecture does it support - is it for x86 or ARM?

Comment: You need to link your c++ interface library (the one that contains all the jni stuff) with the provided .so file. `target_link_libraries` is indeed how you do that in Cmake. Don't forget to ship both .so files!

Comment: @kiner_shah I am using this with NDK